# How to build or get a original latest version of GCC for Windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, c11

I want a latest version of GCC for Windows.
Now the latest version is 9.2 but for Windows via MinGW it is just 8.1...
I have tried to build from source for Windows 10 include WSL, but have not found how to do it exactly, I do not want use via CygWin or other emulater, just real on Windows as clang and MSVC.
Note: I have Windows 10 latest version with WSL.

Comment: I found instructions for _building_ 9.1 https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/04/building-gcc-wsl-windows-subsystem-linux/

Comment: MingW-W64 appears to have 8.1 as well. http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/versions

Comment: I have seen these, the first is on WSL, not on Windows directly, and the second isn't a latest version, it's version 8.1 and not 9.2.

Comment: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-gcc

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of GCC (9.2.0) compiler combined with the latest MinGW-w64 (7.0.0) headers and libraries can be found in the standalone build at http://winlibs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Oh the pain, getting a working GCC for Windows.

#### build your own?

Building is a fun experience, or a no-fun experience, depending on how you look at it.
I've spent literally *weeks* of time building GCC successfully and unsuccessfully (native and cross). Follow the instructions to the letter, and it works. And then, another day, it doesn't work (with the slightest different sub-sub-release or revision, or the tiniest little change that is entirely "harmless", or to the best of your knowledge *no change at all*, and you never get it to build again).
Save everything you've done (copy console), keep the build tree, and repeat the build  (paste text) 6 months later after first doing a `svn update`. Compiles fine for 15-20 minutes, then fails. Start from scratch, and spend a day or two until it works, and you cannot tell why it works now.
Use a build script by someone who offers binary builds (so the assumption is that it *must* work, otherwise where do the binaries come from). The build script more or less does exactly what you've done by hand anyway, and it works, or maybe doesn't work. If you are only interested in actually *having a compiler that works for compiling under Windows*, and not in spending your life fiddling around, that's not a lot of fun.

#### use a pre-built binary?

There exists serval binary distros from a variety of sources.

Although downloading binaries is of course always a tidbid risky (even when scanning everything before you run it, malware scanners are nowhere near perfect, or even *good* or *halfway reliable*), compilers are particularly high-risk. That's because compilers are a very interesting target for malware distributors as they get free redistribution with everything you build.
I've actually seen GCC builds with malware built-in on *apparently* harmless sites (forgot the name, but one such example was a site offering GCC builds for several architectures, which looked very nice).

Now... there exists a distro which supports GCC 9.2 since some time built by *someone* under the pseudonym "nuwen".
It turns out, that "nuwen" is actually Stephan T. Lavavej, so... chances are that this is a distro that you actually want to use (I'm using it anyway). It's unlikely that you will be able build one yourself that's substantially better (also that one has a lot of useful support libs already coming with it), and it's unlikely that it is harmful.

https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

<sub>Note that MSYS2 will also allow you to install a very recent GCC (9.1 or 9.2, not sure) via `pacman`, very fast and very trouble-free. MSYS2 is nice insofar as you get a 95% working Unix-like working environment with 95% of the tools.

And 95% of the time, it works fine in every practical respect. Until then, one day, it *doesn't*, usually related to some `configure` script messing up pathnames, or something with environment variables. Or something else very subtle. For example, it is very much possible to successfully build GCC with MSYS2 (I've done it), and it works "perfectly fine" until some weeks later you discover that *something* doesn't work in your custom build, so some old project of yours now suddenly doesn't build any more when it did with the old stock compiler.

That's probably issues that one could fix, if determined (I'm however too lazy, for me a compiler is something that simply **must** work).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There are two well known distributions of the GCC bundle for Windows. The first one is by equation.com

http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran

and the second one is by winlibs.com

http://winlibs.com/

Comment: thank it is really easy and save a lot of time